# RegEx validation?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having some issues validating my form with RegEx, fname, lname are text only but upon testing it  does not work when I enter the regex, almost like it's not reading it on the form I get the same alert over and over as if the field is empty or filled in wrong.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
function validateForm(){

    var name_value =  document.getElementById("name")
    var flname = (/^[a-zA-Z]$/)

    if (!document.myForm.fname.value.match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/') ) {

        alert("Please fill in your First name!");
        return false;
    }

    if (!document.myForm.lname.value.match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/')) {

        alert("Please fill in your Last name!");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Don't quote the regex as string

Comment: try this `if (!document.myForm.fname.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/) ) { ...`

Comment: Or you can just change the input to `<input id="fname" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />` and it will be automatically validated for you.

Comment: @soktinpk why don't you post that as an answer?  It makes it easier to find, accept, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5 validation:

```html
<form>
  <input id="fname" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />
  <!-- Note that you can't actually submit since it's in a stack snippet -->
  <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

This will automatically tell the user that the input is invalid if it is
blank or doesn't match the regex: `/[a-zA-Z]+`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `test` function of `RegExp` instance and don't use strings, unless of course in `RegExp` constructor. BTW, you can add `required` attribute to make things hassle-free.

```
function validateForm() {
    var name_value = document.getElementById("name"), regx  = /^[a-zA-Z]$/;
    if (!regx.test(document.myForm.fname.value)) {
        alert("Please fill in your First name!");
        return false;
    }
    if (!regx.test(document.myForm.lname.value)) {
        alert("Please fill in your Last name!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it doesnt give the error, just skips the form when you hit submit in general, strange. It works when i enter a string in to the oritional code such as 'julie' or something, just not a regex..